# CSS compatibility issues with IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-tables

I'm using table to show some data,but has the following BUG with IE8:

The right of the text is hidden.

[image]

**I have set the following properties:**

1. `table-layout:fixed;`(Do not want to modify this.)
2. `td {padding: 3px;}`

**Debugged with IE8,Found the following problem:**

The div tag in td is overflowing the td's Boundary.

[image]

What reason? Please help.

Comment: You're going to need to show code, preferably in something like a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

set `box-sizing: content-box` on the `td` containing the `div`

IE8 defaults to `border-box`, all newer versions and all other browsers default to `content-box`

Comment: Sorry，have not solve the bug.
Because I have set <!DOCTYPE, now does not exist box mode problem.